# How to update the value of a boolean variable in swift?

Tags: object, swift, parse-platform, boolean, data-retrieval

I've spent the past 3 days trying to figure this out. I can easily do what I want to do in Java but as soon as I try to do it in Swift, Xcode gives me a hard time.

In this case, I am trying to retrieve a boolean object from Parse that will tell me whether the user's email has been verified. For some reason, whenever I tell to code to check to see if the object is false, `checkEmail` is apparently nil. Also worth noting, if I `println(checkEmail)` right after `var checkEmail = User["emailVerified"] as Bool` I get the correct boolean value (true or false).

Its looks like as soon as the code leaves the query function, the value for `checkEmail` is lost.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class RegisterEmail: UIViewController {

var checkEmail: Bool?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "passEmail" {

        var query = PFUser.query()
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("vFu93HatwL") {
            (User: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                NSLog("%@", User)
            } else {
                NSLog("%@", error)
            }

            let checkEmail = User["emailVerified"] as Bool


            println(checkEmail) //I get the correct value here

        }   

        println(checkEmail) //The value is lost here

        if (checkEmail == false) {

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Error"
            alert.message = "The email you have provided has not been verified."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Dismiss")
            alert.show()

            return false
        }

        else {

            return true
        }
    }

    // by default, transition
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: You have to move the declaration of checkEmail outside of query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("vFu93HatwL") {  ,

Comment: That isn't the only problem here. getObjectInBackgroundWithId() is asynchronous, so the second log still wouldn't be correct because checkEmail wouldn't have a value at this point.

Comment: Wait...stupid question I know, but how can I change the value of a variable....Xcode is given me a bunch of BS errors. I know, this is an easy concept (I can do it in Java).....and checkEmail is declared at the top of my code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included what errors you are receiving and where. And you may have declared a property checkEmail, but you're creating a new local variable of the same name, which takes precedence over the property in the local scope.

Comment: Never mind about the BS errors, I figured it out, I just put self. in front of the variable names. Anyways, back on topic, even when I remove the local declaration of the variable, I still loose the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not assigning the new value to the object property, you're assigning it to a local variable.  Get rid of the `let` keyword, which declares a new local variable, in:

```
let checkEmail = User["emailVerified"] as Bool
```

Comment: doesn't work. I get an error saying I need to add "self.". When I do that, it still doesn't fix the problem.